# How to display property in my reactjs component?

Tags: reactjs

In my component I have :

```
function Message(msg) {
        //console.log('msg=', msg);
        return (
                <div>
                    {
                        msg ?
                                <div>{msg}</div> :
                                <div>Nothing</div>
                    }
                </div>
        )
    }
```

When I try to render this component in my IDE I get this chromeconsole-error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
>   with keys {msg}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use
>   an array instead.

How can I display the msg value ie 'hi' in my component?
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4stx71w0/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is, in function argument you will get the `props` object so `msg` (just the argument name) will have the values of props, because syntax is:

```
function Name (props){
    ...
}
```

And in props you are passing `msg` that's why it is throwing the error:

> found: object with keys {msg})

So either use `{msg.msg}` like this:

```
function Message(msg) {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                msg.msg ?
                    <div>{msg.msg}</div> :
                    <div>Nothing</div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or use destructuring and write it like this:

```
function Message({ msg }) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to:

```
 function Message({msg}) {
```

Because that function receives an object 'props' with msg key.

Other ways:

```
 function Message(props) 
  ... {props.msg}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've shared, the 'msg' variable is an object 
`{msg: 'hi'}`, so you've to access the property to display the string.

```
                {
                    msg ?
                            <div>{msg.msg}</div> :
                            <div>Nothing</div>
                }
```

Cleaner way would be to use ES6 destructuring.

```
function Message({msg}) {
.
.
{
    msg ?
        <div>{msg}</div> :
        <div>Nothing</div>
}
.
.
```